# Switch between plotOutput and plotlyOutput based on a checkbox

Tags: r, plot, shiny, plotly

I'm trying to build a Shiny app that only loads `plotly` if a user marks a checkbox for interactive figures. However, what I've tried so far ends up plotting both figures, regardless of the checkbox value:

```
require('plotly')
require('shiny')

ui <- fluidPage(

  tabsetPanel(
    id = 'mainTab',

    tabPanel(
      'conditionally interactive tab',

      checkboxInput(
        inputId = 'interactive', label = 'Interactive figure', value = FALSE
      ),

      conditionalPanel(
        condition = 'input.interactive == TRUE',
        plotlyOutput('interactivePlot')
      ),

      conditionalPanel(
        condition = 'input.interactive == FALSE',
        plotOutput('staticPlot')
      )
    ),
    tabPanel('unrelated tab')
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

  output$interactivePlot <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(iris, x = ~Petal.Length, y = ~Sepal.Length)
  })

  output$staticPlot <- renderPlot({
    plot(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length, iris)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The reasons for this are the longer loading times when using plotly, and the inconvenience of plotly on handheld devices (trying to scroll with a plot that reacts to touch is difficult). I'd prefer not having separate tabs for them, but I realize that if nothing else works, that might be an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close. The expression inside the conditionalPanel's `condition` is a JavaScript expression, nor an R expression. In JavaScript, they use `true`/`false` rather than `TRUE`/`FALSE`. So just change that and it'll work.

```
require('plotly')
require('shiny')

ui <- fluidPage(

        tabsetPanel(
                id = 'mainTab',

                tabPanel(
                        'conditionally interactive tab',

                        checkboxInput(
                                inputId = 'interactive', label = 'Interactive figure', value = FALSE
                        ),

                        conditionalPanel(
                                condition = 'input.interactive == true',
                                plotlyOutput('interactivePlot')
                        ),

                        conditionalPanel(
                                condition = 'input.interactive == false',
                                plotOutput('staticPlot')
                        )
                ),
                tabPanel('unrelated tab')
        )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

        output$interactivePlot <- renderPlotly({
                plot_ly(iris, x = ~Petal.Length, y = ~Sepal.Length)
        })

        output$staticPlot <- renderPlot({
                plot(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length, iris)
        })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: If I were to use a list of options with `checkboxGroupInput()`, how could I translate something line `'option1' %in% input$options` to JavaScript?

Comment: In the spirit of "teach a man how to fish".... :) Google for something along the lines of "javascript does array contain string"

Comment: Thanks again, had no luck Googling set membership! (fixed it with `options.indexOf("option1") > -1`)